# Regular expressions in javascript and replace method

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I Have string var:

```
Some text...<div class=example><pre><ul><li>Item</li></ul></pre><div class=showExample></div></div>Some text...
```

I want replace all < and > chars in pre tag to html entity = `&lt;` and `&gt;`
So i wrote this Script:

```
text = text.replace(new RegExp("(?=(<pre>.*))<(?=(.*</pre>))","ig"),"&lt;");
text = text.replace(new RegExp("(?=(<pre>.*))>(?=(.*</pre>))","ig"),"&gt;");
```

I always get this result:

```
<p>Some text...<div class=example>&lt;pre><ul><li>Item</li></ul></pre><div class=showExample></div></div>Some text...</p>
```

Why???

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson I don't think that it's a possible duplicate. The is a valid one about the behaviour of regex. OP is not parsing the the html with regex, which is different. It could have been on another text other than html.

Comment: @Jerry he _is_ using regex to parse HTML. He's using regex to find the pre tags. Just use a DOM parser

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson The question isn't itself about parsing the html, but about _why_ the behaviour of the regex was such. There is a difference there.

Comment: @Jerry yes. But he still shouldn't be doing it.

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson That's not a reason to disregard a learning opportunity.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of your first lookahead: `(?=(<pre>.*))`. When the cursor of the regex is right before `<pre>`, it matches since you have a `<` and there is `<pre>` ahead.

You probably intended to have a lookbehind there `(?<= ... )` instead, but javascript doesn't support them.

I'm not familiar with JS, but it might be easier to first extract the stuff within the `<pre>` tags:

```
match = text.match(/<pre>(.*?)<\/pre>/)[1];
```

Then replace all you need to replace in this little group:

```
match = match.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
```

Then replace it back into the original:

```
text = text.replace(/<pre>.*?<\/pre>/g, '<pre>'+match+'</pre>');
```

As said before, I'm not familiar with JS, but I guess you can run a loop to replace multiple texts within those `<pre>` tags.

For your example, here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tWj7v/1/).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you're better off using jQuery to html encode/decode, then using Regex, since it would break on more complex markup.

You have example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1219983/186822).